# doing work after onSaveInstanceState of Fragment

Tags: android

I have a Fragments which save user data in their onSaveInstanceState method. 
I need to get this data when the user finishes the activity and display it in the next intent.
Currently the sequence of my implementation is:

1. user hits the close button
2. computation starts relying of data stored in prev calls of onSaveInstanceState, then start new intent
3. onSaveInstanceState of current fragments get called, information is missed in calculation
4. new Activity displays
5. old Activitys onDestroy is called

I thought about starting my calculation and the new activity in onDestroy. Then I need a mechanism to destroy the current Activity.
Or I could somehow call all remaining onSaveInstanceState method calls in the current thread before doing the calculation.
What would be better or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a strange design to me for android. For this use case I would do:

1. user presses abitratry button (in your case close)
2. click listener gets the needed data (the same way you would get them in onSaveInstanceState)
3. start an asynctask if lengthly operation and show progress bar or make computation on UI thread if trivial
4. start intent with computation result for new activity

> I have a Fragments which save user data in their onSaveInstanceState method. I need to get this data when the user finishes the activity and display it in the next intent.

Is there any reason you need the data specially from onSaveInstanceState() method?

> thought about starting my calculation and the new activity in onDestroy. Then I need a mechanism to destroy the current Activity.

If you call something in onDestroy() there is no need to forcefully destroy the activity since its already in progress. (btw. finish() would do it). Appart from that, onDestroy should do clean up procedures e.g. free resources or close streams, not for calling new activities

Comment: Are you actually storing (I mean a lenghtly process) data in your db or whatever in onSaveInstanceState()? I dont get what you mean with "to the onClickListeners off all interactive UI elements"?

Comment: Storing is not a lengthly process. At first I did the storage in onClickListeners of every interactive UI element. I need to store the user inputs of each fragment for later retrieval in another session. I had issues if the application is going into background and the device runs out of memory. This erases all class elements. onSaveInstanceState and onCreate(SavedBundle) handles this convenient.

Comment: Well yes if you talking adding stuff to the out-bundle, I get that, but what has this to do with your computation use case, if the user presses a button and you start the calculation there is zero chance that your activty gets destroyed if its still visibile to the user, so its safe to get your data from the input fields in the onclicklistener (in this is pretty much the way to do it)